# optimizing certain filters only in cnn models

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

So I'm trying to train my model (`resnet50`) but I'm fixing most parameters and only optimizing certain filters that I choose using the function filters to unfreeze. I then set the required grad of these filters to true and append the filters (not the whole layer) to `params` to update which is the list of tensors that I passed to my optimizer.

my problem is that when I pass whole layers to the optimizer I notice that after training their values change however when I pass certain filters , after training the weights of these filters are not changed.

I already verified that the right filters are added to `params` to update and their required grad is set to true. Does anyone know why it does not work with filters
[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQYYp.png)

Comment: As a sanity chek: In your code you only ever set `requires_grad=True`. Did you check it's actually set to `False` for the ones you do not want to train?

Comment: @Scriddie i actually do set them to false just earlier on in the code.